# Rails & bootstrap template Less Parse Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, less

Have a problem with adding a bootstrap less template to rails app.
getting a Less::ParseError .transition is undefined after i drop a less folder in **app/assets/stylesheets** Any idea how resolve this issue?

**Rails 4.1**

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass'
    gem 'less-rails'
    gem 'therubyracer'
    gem 'bootstrap'

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
      gem "minitest"
      gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
      gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
      gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
      gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
      gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
      gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'sass-rails'
    gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
    gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
    gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

    group :doc do
      gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
      gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
    end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```

**application.css.scss**

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require the-story.less
 *= require config.less
 *= require buttons.less
 *= require bootstrap.less
 */
```

Comment: Do you mean you droped a folder containing LESS files, and now LESS is failing to compile? I'd say that I am not surprise of the result. Try restoring the droper folder maybe?

Comment: Your `application.js` and `application.css.scss` content is *exactly* same. Is that a typo? `application.css.scss` should have content like `*= require_tree .` (with leading `*=`) and NOT ` //= require_tree .` (with leading `//=`)

Comment: so what i need to do friends, please help me with this issue
@MrYoshiji what you mean by restoring a droper folder?